# how to extract parts of the string

Tags: php, string, explode, substr

I have the following string in PHP.

```
"File:content/resources/11933/Calm_Nebula_by_The_Free_Mason.jpgDate:Fri Mar 18 11:30:17 CET 2016Size:23124"
```

I need to fetch file, date, and size separately.

What is the best way to extract the required values?

```
explode() OR substring()
```

Explode requires some common value, substring requires start and end. In both cases i am a bit confuse.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might find regular expressions useful. See [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

Comment: Are there really no other separating characters, e.g. between the date and the word `Size`.... if not, then you might need to use a combination of explode and substr

Comment: Use regex for pattern recognition.

Comment: Have a look at regular expressions http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: I was hoping if there could be a way to avoid using regular expression as i am not very good at it. :(

Comment: Or even [split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) would resolve your issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$text = "File:content/resources/11933/Calm_Nebula_by_The_Free_Mason.jpgDate:Fri Mar 18 11:30:17 CET 2016Size:23124";
$pattern = '/file:(.*?)date:(.*?)size:(.*)/i';
preg_match($pattern, $text, $out);
print_r($out);
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => File:content/resources/11933/Calm_Nebula_by_The_Free_Mason.jpgDate:Fri Mar 18 11:30:17 CET 2016Size:23124 
    [1] => content/resources/11933/Calm_Nebula_by_The_Free_Mason.jpg
    [2] => Fri Mar 18 11:30:17 CET 2016
    [3] => 23124
)
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/OcSXH